# Unable to parse UTF-16 encoded XML in IE using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have tried to parse an XML encoded with UTF-16 by using jQuery and it failed in Internet Explorer 10 and 11. Is there any way to parse UTF-16 encoded XML using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

To the head tag of your html page loading the xml file.